# Twitter bootstrap, radio and checkbox layouts are broken?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am wondering if some one can tell me, based on this html:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="carousel_home" class="carousel"   name="aisis_options[carousel_home]" value="carousel_home"> 
        Remove the carousel from the home page only.
    </label>
</div>
```

Why my check boxes look like this:

**Note:**

There is no styling applied to either the id or the class, of either the input or the label. Theses are interacted with js.

I am using pure bootstrap styling with no third party styles. I have checked the class `checkbox`, `carousel` and the id `carousel_home` - there is **no** css attached to them that could cause this.

This happens in Chrome (latest), FF (latest) and IE 10

[image]

Comment: Can you make jsfiddle.?